# How to get and set data attributes of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to implement 3D vector in Python that stores its components in a numpy array (or another container). And I want to access the components as `x`, `y` and `z` in order to get and set them. What is the best way to do it?

I implemented it like this:

```
import numpy as np

class Vector3d:
    components = ['x', 'y', 'z']

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.components:
            index = self.components.index(key)
            return self._data[index]
        else:
            return super().__getattr__(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.components:
            index = self.components.index(key)
            self._data[index] = value
        else:
            return super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._data)

    def norm(self):
        return np.linalg.norm(self._data)

a = Vector3d()
a.x = 1.2
a.y = 2.3
a.z = 3.4
print(a.x, a.y, a.z)
print(a)
print(a.norm())
```

What I dislike in it. First, I duplicated the code `if key in self.components: index = self.components.index(key)`. Second, searching for the index every time seems to be non-optimal towards the consuming time. I believe there's a better way to implement it. Please, suggest me your approaches.

I'm searching for a solution for Python 3.

Comment: Er, why not have have variables `x`, `y` and `z` and have getter and setter functions? The optimisation issue will not be any more...
Do you really want to make it so generic with 'x', 'y' and 'z' in the list?  Alternatively, why not use a dictionary, and have a try catch, with return of vec['x'], where vec is the dictionary replacing `components`, and 'x' will be passed as `value` to getter/setter.

Comment: There may be many reasons. For example, I may want to store the components as `(ctypes.c_double * 3)` array and to pass them to a DLL to gain performance of some calculations. Or to store them as `numpy.array` having the access to all numpy array methods. But I still want to keep the access to components through x, y, z from the outside.

Comment: You're basically saying, you need to have some kind of an array...? Can you update your question with one of the ways you might be using the class? Cuz if you're going to access as shown above, `a.x`, `a.y` and `a.z`, i'd create variables x, y and z and when I'd like to get the vector, i'd have a method return the values of x, y and z in a tuple, or a list.

Comment: @Harsh I have updated. Please, look.

Comment: You may mark the question as solved by accepting the solution if it did the job!

Comment: You might get ideas by looking at the class definitions for `record` and `recarray` in `numpy.core.records.py`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, the comment section seems constricting, so I'll move here...

Here is what I made out, ordered by priority:

1. You do not like how `if key in self.components` is linearly searching for the component `x` (or others).
2. You do not like that repeating piece of code.

Maybe this is something that can work:

```
import numpy as np

class Vector3d:
    components = {'x':0, 'y':1, 'z':2}

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self._data[components[key]] ###!!!

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self._data[components[key]] = value ###!!!

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._data)

    def norm(self):
        return np.linalg.norm(self._data)

a = Vector3d()
a.x = 1.2
a.y = 2.3
a.z = 3.4
print(a.x, a.y, a.z)
print(a)
print(a.norm())
```

1. The **search is now not linear**, so it's a little more optimal than what you wrote.
2. The multiple lines of repeating code is now gone, but that `self._data[components[key]]` is something we got to live with! :D

You can add a `try` and `catch` to access data from `super()` in case the `return self._data[components[key]]` fails!